# arcs constraints for jobshop Scheduling

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I have built a job shop scheduling algorithm using the ortools optimization library for python.
the problem is when i made a flexible jobshop model with setup times it doesn't work and i think  it is due to the arcs that i made, if there is anybody here who can explain more the circuit constraint, that would help me. By the way when i use a single machine it works.

Code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import collections

from google.protobuf import text_format
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

# Import Python wrapper for or-tools CP-SAT solver.
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

# Intermediate solution printer
class SolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    def __init__(self):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.__solution_count = 0

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        """Called after each new solution found."""
        print('Solution %i, time = %f s, objective = %i' %
              (self.__solution_count, self.WallTime(), self.ObjectiveValue()))
        self.__solution_count += 1

def MinimalJobshopSat():
    """Minimal jobshop problem."""
    # Create the model.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    jobs_data = [[(0, 2546), (1, 2000), (2, 1400)],
 [(0, 1289), (1, 2546), (2, 2546)],
 [(0, 2839), (1, 1576), (2, 1200)]
]

    setup_times = [
        [
        [3559, 1638, 2000],
        [1442, 3010, 1641],
        [1728, 3583, 3243]],
        [
        [3559, 1638, 2000],
        [1442, 3010, 1641],
        [1728, 3583, 3243]],
        [
        [3559, 1638, 2000],
        [1442, 3010, 1641],
        [1728, 3583, 3243]]
        ]

    all_jobs = range(len(jobs_data))   

    machines_count = 1 + max(task[0] for job in jobs_data for task in job)
    all_machines = range(machines_count)

    for machine in all_machines:
        for job_id in all_jobs:
            min_incoming_setup = min(
                setup_times[machine][j][job_id] for j in all_jobs)
            if min_incoming_setup == 0:
                continue

            print('job %i at machine %i has a min incoming setup of %i' %
                  (job_id, machine, min_incoming_setup))
            # We can transfer some setup times to the duration of the job.
            jobs_data[job_id][machine] = (machine, jobs_data[job_id][machine][1] + min_incoming_setup)
            # Decrease corresponding incoming setup times.
            for j in all_jobs:
                setup_times[machine][j][job_id] -= min_incoming_setup

    # Computes horizon dynamically as the sum of all durations.
    horizon = sum(task[1] for job in jobs_data for task in job)

    for times in setup_times:
        for  time in times:
            horizon += max(time)

    # Named tuple to store information about created variables.
    task_type = collections.namedtuple('task_type', 'start end interval')
    # Named tuple to manipulate solution information.
    assigned_task_type = collections.namedtuple('assigned_task_type',
                                                'start job index duration')

    # Creates job intervals and add to the corresponding machine lists.
    all_tasks = {}
    machine_to_intervals = collections.defaultdict(list)
    starts = collections.defaultdict(list)
    ends = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for job_id, job in enumerate(jobs_data):
        for task_id, task in enumerate(job):
            machine = task[0]
            duration = task[1]
            suffix = '_%i_%i' % (job_id, task_id)
            start_var = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'start' + suffix)
            end_var = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'end' + suffix)
            interval_var = model.NewIntervalVar(start_var, duration, end_var,
                                                'interval' + suffix)
            all_tasks[job_id, task_id] = task_type(
                start=start_var, end=end_var, interval=interval_var)
            machine_to_intervals[machine].append(interval_var)
            starts[machine].append(start_var)
            ends[machine].append(end_var)

    # Create and add disjunctive constraints.
    for machine in all_machines:   
        model.AddNoOverlap(machine_to_intervals[machine])
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Transition times using a circuit constraint.
    list_arcs = []
    for machine in all_machines:
        arcs = []
        for i in all_jobs:
            # Initial arc from the dummy node (0) to a task.
            start_lit = model.NewBoolVar('')
            arcs.append([0, i + 1, start_lit])
            # If this task is the first, set to minimum starting time.
            min_start_time = min(0,setup_times[machine][0][i])
            model.Add(starts[machine][i] == min_start_time).OnlyEnforceIf(start_lit)
            # Final arc from an arc to the dummy node.
            arcs.append([i + 1, 0, model.NewBoolVar('')])

            for j in all_jobs:
                if i == j:
                    continue

                lit = model.NewBoolVar('%i_%i follows %i_%i' % (j, machine, i, machine))
                arcs.append([i + 1, j + 1, lit])

                # We add the reified precedence to link the literal with the times of the
                # two tasks.
                # If release_dates[j] == 0, we can strenghten this precedence into an
                # equality as we are minimizing the makespan.

                model.Add(starts[machine][j] >=
                          ends[machine][i] + setup_times[machine][i][j]).OnlyEnforceIf(lit)
        list_arcs.append(arcs)
        model.AddCircuit(arcs)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Precedences inside a job.
    for job_id, job in enumerate(jobs_data):
        for task_id in range(len(job) - 1):
            model.Add(all_tasks[job_id, task_id +
                                1].start >= all_tasks[job_id, task_id].end)

    # Makespan objective.
    obj_var = model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, 'makespan')
    model.AddMaxEquality(obj_var, [
        all_tasks[job_id, len(job) - 1].end
        for job_id, job in enumerate(jobs_data)
    ])
    model.Minimize(obj_var)

    # Solve model.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 60
    status=solver.Solve(model)
    solver.parameters
    solution_printer = SolutionPrinter()
    solver.SolveWithSolutionCallback(model, solution_printer)
    print(solver.ResponseStats())


    if status == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
        # Create one list of assigned tasks per machine.
        assigned_jobs = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for job_id, job in enumerate(jobs_data):
            for task_id, task in enumerate(job):
                machine = task[0]
                assigned_jobs[machine].append(
                    assigned_task_type(
                        start=solver.Value(all_tasks[job_id, task_id].start),
                        job=job_id,
                        index=task_id,
                        duration=task[1]))

        # Create per machine output lines.
        output = ''
        for machine in all_machines:
            # Sort by starting time.
            assigned_jobs[machine].sort()
            sol_line_tasks = 'Machine ' + str(machine) + ': '
            sol_line = '           '

            for assigned_task in assigned_jobs[machine]:
                name = 'job_%i_%i' % (assigned_task.job, assigned_task.index)
                # Add spaces to output to align columns.
                sol_line_tasks += '%-10s' % name

                start = assigned_task.start
                duration = assigned_task.duration
                sol_tmp = '[%i,%i]' % (start, start + duration)
                # Add spaces to output to align columns.
                sol_line += '%-10s' % sol_tmp

            sol_line += '\n'
            sol_line_tasks += '\n'
            output += sol_line_tasks
            output += sol_line

        # Finally print the solution found.
        print('Optimal Schedule Length: %i' % solver.ObjectiveValue())
        print(output)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MinimalJobshopSat()()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a task is optional, you need to add a self looping arc on the node that corresponds to this arc.

So let's assume task_i with Boolean presence literal lit_i, you need to add

```
arcs.append([i + 1, i + 1, lit_i.Not()])
```

Comment: that means the task would not be scheduled?

Comment: if lit_i is false, the task is not scheduled. You need to communicate with the circuit constraint to tell it that the node should not be visited by the hamiltonian path.

Comment: I understood you. but here all the tasks have to be planned. I think the problem is that I have several disjoint graphs and I have to link them , taking into account the sequence of the tasks, which makes the problem more difficult.

Comment: if you could just explain the role of the dummy node i would think of a solution of this problem, now i found a problem understanding the dummy node

Comment: The dummy node is the start and the end of the schedule. Remember you need a cycle. Outgoing arcs indicate which task is first. Incoming arcs indicate which task is last.